# Google Maps mapView is only gray only on iMessage app

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, imessage-extension

I am working on an iMessage app for which I'd like to have access to google maps. Despite following the tutorial for [getting started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start), the map presents the google logo and stays grey. The common solve for this is making sure the API Key is bound to the right bundle identifier and that the associated account has the Maps SDK enabled. **I have checked all of the identifier, API Key, and status of "Google Maps SDK for iOS" in the google console. All of these are fine and set as expected from typical troubleshooting.** When I run the code that displays the map, there are no print statements indicating an issue with anything related to the Maps SDK.

In trying to debug, I created a non-iMessage app and tried to load a map using the same API Key. **The map loaded in this case**.

Note that the one deviation from the tutorial is that since iMessage apps don't have an AppDelegate class, I have called the ".provideAPIKey(...)" method in the viewDidLoad of the first view controller in my app. **Doing the same for the non-iMessage app had no impact on it's ability to present a map**

This API Key uses google places, which functions just fine on the iMessage app. Is there anything special I need to do to get google maps working in iMessage apps? If not, what are common debugging approaches to handle iMessage apps and the google sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I have contacted Google's support team with contained examples and they have been able to replicate the bug on their end. Their engineers are working on it, and I will update this answer when they have.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).